# react-router-component Routes All URLs to same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-component

I am trying to add routing to my simple blogging/short stories app with react-router-component, but no matter what url is entered it shows the same component. The url appears, but it's always the same component that is rendered even though I specified a different handler, so "localhost:3000/" and "localhost:3000/category" both show the same component even though I specified a different handler for "/category". The file looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router-component');
var Locations = Router.Locations;
var Location = Router.Location;
var MainPage = require('./components/views/main-page.jsx');
var CategoryPage = require('./components/views/category-page.jsx');

var App = React.createClass({

  render: function () {
    return (
      <Locations>
        <Location path="/" handler={MainPage} />
        <Location path="/category" handler={CategoryPage} />
      </Locations>
    )
  }
})

React.render(<App />, document.body)
```

You can view the full project on my github https://github.com/mrbgit/short-stories/tree/branch Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: You're not running your router and that's not how you create routes in React-Router. The tutorial in react-router is very straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using react-router-component, not react-router, but I figured out the answer. I needed to add "hash" to the locations. So it works like this:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router-component');
var Locations = Router.Locations;
var Location = Router.Location;
var MainPage = require('./components/views/main-page.jsx');
var CategoryPage = require('./components/views/category-page.jsx');

var App = React.createClass({

  render: function () {
    return (
      <Locations hash>
        <Location path="/" handler={MainPage} />
        <Location path="/category" handler={CategoryPage} />
      </Locations>
    )
  }
})

React.render(<App />, document.body)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer from another post, it will give you an idea of how it works:[React-Router StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360960/react-router-default-route-redirect-to-home/31372212#31372212)

You need to use `<Route handler.../> and <RouteHandler />`. If you take the code from the person asking and use my adjustments, you will have a better idea of how it works.